# Find where given frame (image) appears in video

Tags: video

I have an image that corresponds (maybe inaccurately) to some frame in a video, and I want to find out where (at what time) this image appears.

Under inaccurate image matching I mean that the image may come from another video file with the same content but in different resolution, slightly color corrected, more blurred or grained, etc.

In other words, the desired program must perform similar image search on each video frame.

Preferably desktop, free, and with broad support of video codecs. But will consider other options also.

Do not offer extract all video frames to individual images, it'll take too much disk space and time.

[Similar question on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/663731/find-video-file-position-using-an-image-match) (without a correct answer currently).

Comment: Could you clarify the nature of "maybe inaccurately"? Image matching gets complex very quickly outside of exact matches. Also, this is specialist enough that maybe no packaged software could do it, but definitely something like OpenCV could do it if you have time to program something against its API.

Comment: @NeilSlater I've updated the question, added info about inaccuracy